# HttpsStatusCodeException returning null: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Here I am using Junit5 and I am mocking the rest template call to return a HttpClientErrorException, but instead, a null pointer exception is thrown. I am not able to figure out why Null is returned at the specified lines.

**Rest Call**

```
ResponseEntity<Object> obj;
try{
     obj=restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestObj, Object.class);    
}catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex){

    ex.getMessage();

   throw new CustomError(ex.getStatusCode()); //ex.getStatusCode is Null and throws Null Pointer Exception
}catch(Exception ex){
  throw....
}
```

**Testing**

```
@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate;


when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),eq(Object.class)))
    .thenThrow(HttpClientErrorException.class);

HttpStatus status= Assertions.assertThrows(CustomError.class,()->obj.methodName()).getHttpStatus();

Assertions.assertTrue(status.is4xxClientError()); //500 is thrown Null pointer exception
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to fix this issue, you need to provide a mock of `HttpClientErrorException` and its methods in use or you need to pass an instance of the exception object to the throw statement.

```
    HttpClientErrorException mockedException = mock(HttpClientErrorException.class);
    when(mockedException.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    ...
    when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),eq(Object.class)))
.thenThrow(mockedException);
```

or

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),eq(Object.class)))
.thenThrow( new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```